# pipenv and rpy2 - Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no command 'R' in the PATH

Tags: python, r, virtualenv, rpy2, pipenv

I'm trying to use pipenv on a data analysis project and have a need to use the [Twitter Anomaly Detection package](https://github.com/twitter/AnomalyDetection) which is in R.

I'm getting an error trying to `pipenv install rpy2`

Below is my code creating a pipenv folder and trying to install rpy2 into it.

```
PS C:\Users\amaguire\Documents\LocalWork\rp2_pipenv_example> pipenv --python 3.7
Creating a virtualenv for this project…
Pipfile: C:\Users\amaguire\Documents\LocalWork\rp2_pipenv_example\Pipfile
Using C:/Users/amaguire/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/python.exe (3.7.0) to create virtualenv…
Running virtualenv with interpreter C:/Users/amaguire/AppData/Local/Continuum/anaconda3/python.exe
Using base prefix 'C:\\Users\\amaguire\\AppData\\Local\\Continuum\\anaconda3'
New python executable in C:\Users\amaguire\.virtualenvs\rp2_pipenv_example-MDtFv_K4\Scripts\python.exe
Installing setuptools, pip, wheel...
done.

Virtualenv location: C:\Users\amaguire\.virtualenvs\rp2_pipenv_example-MDtFv_K4
Creating a Pipfile for this project…
PS C:\Users\amaguire\Documents\LocalWork\rp2_pipenv_example> pipenv install rpy2
Installing rpy2…
Collecting rpy2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/f1/98/c7652cc9d7fc0afce74d2c30a52b9c9ac391713a63d037e4ab8feb56c530/rpy2-2.9.4.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no command 'R' in the PATH.

    ----------------------------------------

Error:  An error occurred while installing rpy2!
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\amaguire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-8h23my82\rpy2\

This is likely caused by a bug in rpy2. Report this to its maintainers.
PS C:\Users\amaguire\Documents\LocalWork\rp2_pipenv_example>
```

I had a look but could not find much by way of examples of people using rpy2 in a virtualenv or with pipenv.

Am curious as to if anytihng i can do to make rpy2 in the virtualenv know where R lives (if that is whats going on).

Any advice much appreciated, i'd imagine could be useful for others too to try solve this one.

#### Update

I have added R to my Path variables in windows and am now getting a new error as below. So am hopeful this should solve it once i download Visual C++

```
        ...
copying .\rpy\ipython\html.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\rpy2\ipython
        copying .\rpy\ipython\rmagic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\rpy2\ipython
        copying .\rpy\ipython\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\rpy2\ipython
        creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\rpy2\ipython\tests
        copying .\rpy\ipython\tests\test_rmagic.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\rpy2\ipython\tests
        copying .\rpy\ipython\tests\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.7\rpy2\ipython\tests
        warning: build_py: byte-compiling is disabled, skipping.

        running build_clib
        building 'r_utils' library
        error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/

        ----------------------------------------

    Error:  An error occurred while installing rpy2==2.9.4!
      Failed building wheel for rpy2
    Command "c:\users\amaguire\.virtualenvs\ami-swtbbbw7\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\amaguire\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-kmzhepx1\\rpy2\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\amaguire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-zgsh7n25\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers c:\users\amaguire\.virtualenvs\ami-swtbbbw7\include\site\python3.7\rpy2" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\amaguire\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-kmzhepx1\rpy2\
```

Comment: So, you have installed R and it *is* in your PATH variable?

Comment: @BramVanroy i had added it but think i needed to reboot for it to take effect perhaps. Seems to have done something anyway so looks like i just need visual c++ now hopefully. cheers